# how can i make TextView change Text at Runtime?

Tags: android, textview, repaint

Currently my source looks like this

```
    System.out.println(text1+" "+text2); // displays the correct values.

    this.view1.setText(""+text1); // should display the same values
    this.view1.setText(""+text2); //

    ((Activity)getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        { invalidate(); }
    });
```

This is part of a method which is called by another object every 30 seconds.
The TextViews are placed on a LinearLayout.

The text which is displayd at start is "0".
Now i want it to change every 30 seconds to display the given text ( for example "5" and "10").

It seems that the views do not repaint.

I hope to have made it clear. Thanks!

Comment: looking at the sample you are rewriting text1 with text2 with the last setText() method

Comment: Do you set the Text in the UI Thread?

Comment: can not understand your question..u mean like a timer..then u can use chronometer to implement this

Answer (score 0):

maybe you error depends on a wrong object type for "text1" and "text2".
are this variables both String objects or Integer? if you use Integer (int) you need
to convert the variable values to a String:

```
String str1 = String.valueOf(text1);
this.view1.setText(str1);

String str2 = String.valueOf(text2);
this.view2.setText(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the text should not require you to invalidate the TextView to change it.

Are you **sure** you want to do this?

```
this.view1.setText(""+text1); // should display the same values
this.view1.setText(""+text2); //
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `Context` class does not have a `runOnUiThread` method, so you need an `Activity` object to execute this method. And you must call `textView.setText` method inside the `runOnUiThread` method to get it working. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

u can use handler, for updating textview's values.

calling handler with value.

```
    Message m = new Message();
    m.what = -1;
    m.arg1 = remainTime;
handler.sendMessage(m);
 ******* Handler*****                                       
        public static Handler handler = new Handler() {
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                    if (msg.what == -1) {

                        set_timer(msg.arg1);

                    }
        }
        };


        *********Updating Text***************

        public static void set_timer(int time) {

                if (time == 0) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Time Out...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.exit(0);

                } else {
                    if (sec < 10)
                        timeindex.setText(time + " : 0" + sec + " of " + value[0]);
                    else
                        timeindex.setText(time + " : " + sec + " of " + value[0]);
                }

            }
```

Hope u get it....

Answer (score 0):

The real class looks more complicated but this example shows my (working ) answer and should make clear how it can work.

```
public class MyObject extends LinearLayout<br />
{

    private TextView text1,text2;
    private String str_text1, str_text2;

    /* The constructor does the initialisation of all fields ... */
    public MyObject(Context context)
    { /* Initialisation ... */ }

    /*This method is called from outside by a thread to renew the displayed values.*/
    public final void method_A ()
    {
      ((Activity)getContext()).runonUIThread(
        new Runnable()
        {
              public void run()
              {
                  text1.setText(str_text1);
                  text2.setText(str_text2);
              }
        });
    }
    /* This method is called from outside by an object to initialize the two values */
    method_B(String str_text1, String str_text2)
    {
       this.str_text1 = str_text1;
       this.str_text2 = str_text2;
    }
}
```